# How to select an appropriate tone spacing for intermodulation distortion testing?

Tags: measurement, test

Intermodulation distortion measurements require (at least) two closely spaced carriers combined before going into the DUT. I understand the basic theory but have not grasped the effect of the choice of the tone spacing.

Does tone spacing not have any effect on IMD besides the resultant difference frequencies?
Should I be selecting a spacing which is proportional to the channel bandwidth?

e.g. 20 kHz FM receiver - an arbitrary delta of 1-5 kHz?
e.g 2. 5 MHz QPSK device - an arbitrary delta of 1 MHz?

Comment: For BF audio intermodulation of amplifiers, I think there is a standard, if not changed.  see also information on particular device as    https://dl.cdn-anritsu.com/en-us/test-measurement/files/Application-Notes/Application-Note/11410-00859B.pdf

Comment: For audio, answer can be found here      https://www.ap.com/technical-library/more-about-imd/

Comment: " ... have not grasped the effect of the choice of the tone spacing ". The objective of the method (choice of the 2 frequencies) is that measuring of IMD may or must be done with only with ONE point. Spectrum is sometimes very ... large and it may difficult to dress it as standard.